# Some general questions about Android development

Tags: android

I'm looking for general advice on Android development. I want to build an activity looking like this :

> ```
> ----------------------
> |       Button       |
> |                    |
> |      TextView      |
> |                    |
> | ------------------ |
> | |                | |
> | |     Custom     | |
> | |  SurfaceView   | |
> | |                | |
> | |                | |
> | ------------------ |
> ----------------------
> ```

The CustomView has to be defined in a special classs, extending SurfaceView, and implementing Runnable to run on its own thread.

My questions :

1. How do I integrate the CustomSurfaceView in my activity ? I tried to do it by placing the component in the layout file, but I don't know how to connect it in the main Activity. If I instanciate a variable CustomSurfaceView in the main activity, how do I start the main thread ? Does this question even have any sense for you ?
2. I get some datas from my main activity (specifically float vectors from sensors), I'd like to pass them to the "draw" part of my CustomSurfaceView, what is a good way to do this ?

As I'm not providing any code (I could, but I don't think it would help at this stage), I don't ask for precise answers, just some links to good documentation (I'm a two weeks beginner in the matter of Android development).

Sorry if the question seems so vague, I'm trying very hard to understand all this, but it's not clear in my head.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

1)Your question doesn't fully make sense.  If you want to add a custom view to your layout, just put it (by fully qualified class name) in the layout file as a view.  You can get a reference to it via findViewByID.  And you never need to start the main thread, its started for you.  Its what your activity's onCreate is run on.

2)You don't pass data to draw.  Draw is called by the framework.  Your view can have instance data, and you can draw off that state.  To do this, you'd just update that instance data, then call invalidate() on the view when it needs to be redrawn.